# When can a wife use the money she owns or earns without her husband's permission?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, women, marriage, money

Normally, the money that comes to a woman before and during her marriage, she uses to buy land which belongs to her, but the husband has the rights to eat (own) their fruits (dividends​), this is called נכסי מלוג. These are the exceptions:
 1. Money she made from selling "(the rights to) her property, and kesuba"
 2. *Shtar mavrachas* - land that she gave as a gift before the hupa to hide from her husband.
 3. Gifts from her husband.
([Shulchan Aruch, Even Ha'Ezer 85.7](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.85.7))

**Are there other exceptions that'll allow her direct use the money/property she acquired before the death or divorce of her husband?**

For example, when the wife acquires the money through her own labor
1. By the husband forfeiting his right to the money his wife earns
 or
2. By the wife forfeiting her rights to get fed and clothed
([Even Ha'Ezer 80.18](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.80.18) and [69.4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.69.4))

Please provide sources.

Comment: You mean exceptions other than the two you list?

Comment: @mevaqesh the 3 I listed, (the 2 are expample of cases which I am interested in is they are also exceptions)

Comment: Practically in 99.999% of cases they don't worry or care about who owns what, except for a lulav and similar things where it actually matters.

Comment: i was often told this website is not for questions about plactice (who is "they"?)

Comment: Married couples.  No it's not for questions about specific shailos, but there's room for distinction between theoretically who owns what and what people actually do.

Comment: Just like when you buy a new chair, pretty soon you're going to make it tamei moshav.  In principle it's halachic status changes.  In practice until Mashiach comes nobody cares.

Comment: @Heshy knowing who halachikly owns what might be positive (even when no one of them is particular) so that the one that does not own it can appreciate (makir tov) the other one "not caring"

Comment: What are you asking, exactly - are there cases that are hers that aren't nichsei melug or nichsei tzon u'barzel, or if bedieved she spent her ma'aseh yadayim it's not considered gezeilah?

Comment: @DonielF the first one (I did not even think about what happens bedieved (it seems interesting)) and mostly interested regarding the work of her hands (I understand that only things in the kesuba (or at least at the time of marriage)  are tzon barzel)

Comment: @DonielF I brought 3 cases like it I am interested if there are more

Comment: @hazoriz Okay, so we're on the same page then. I'm pretty sure there's a case where the husband and wife agree that she'll keep her ma'aseh yadayim in exchange for forfeiting her kesubah and all of his obligations to her entailed within - if I can find the source, would that count as an answer?

Comment: Also, this site does allow practical sha'alos. All CYLOR means is that if it applies practically to *you* to ask your Rav. The [tag:Halacha] tag exists for a reason. Ask away, just confirm with your Rav before you act on it.

Comment: @DonielF I am not strict on what is considered an answer I usually always give a +1 (for effort), I learned this subject a little an do not understand what you are referring to , the way I understand it is a wife can keep her maasai yodaym if she agreed not to be feed or clothed (the question is does he own the fruits of the leftovers (after she used part of it to support herself) .  if a wife forfits her kesuba she looses all her right (husband's obligations are canceled) , but he still can not have relations with her until he obligates himself the amount of the kesuba itself

Comment: My understanding was that if she forfeited everything - she'eirah kesusah v'onasah plus the fine for divorcing her and the payment from his estate if he predeceases her, and not just food and clothing - then she keeps even the fruits of ma'aseh yadayim. I've never learned kesubos, so I could very well be mistaken.

Comment: @DonielF I guess you are referring to this halacha הַמּוֹחֶלֶת כְּתֻבָּתָהּ לְבַעֲלָהּ, אִבְּדָה כָּל תְּנָאֵי כְּתֻבָּה.  https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.105.4

Comment: @DonielF and this https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Marriage.17.19

Comment: @DonielF regarding rations https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.66.3?lang=bi&p2=Chelkat_Mechokek.66.14 but I see nothing about her obligations to him being cancelled , if you can find a source that yes I would be very interested

Comment: @DonielF btw the fruits are for buying her out if she was kidnapped ( https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.85.1?lang=bi&with=Beit%20Shmuel&lang2=en ) which can not be cancelled (maybe it is not even if she forgives her kesuba but i do not know (and am interested in sources regarding this))

Comment: That's all very interesting. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @hazoriz I believe it was a machlokes in kesubos whether when she forfeits her maaseh yadayim does she only get back the money equal to how much he needs to feed her and etc or does she keep everything. I learnt kesubos last year but I can't remember where in particular it was. I'll try to look it up

Comment: @Orion it seems the halacha is she keeps everything, but my question is can she use it

Comment: @hazoriz why wouldn't she?

Comment: @Orion if it becomes nichsai milog then she can not use it

Answer (score 4):

A list of times where a woman can use money without husbands permission:

1. A married  woman can be given a present on condition that her husband has no ownership and then she should use the present for the sake of her nutrition.
   [Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh Deah 222:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.222.1?lang=bi):
   המודר מחתנו והוא רוצה לתת לבתו מעות כדי שתהא נהנית בהם ומוציאה אותם בחפציה הרי זה נותן לה ואומר לה הרי המעות הללו נתונים לך במתנה ובלבד שלא יהא לבעליך רשות בהן אלא יהיו למה שאת נותנת לתוך פיך או למה שתלבשי וכיוצא בזה ואפי' אמר על מנת שאין לבעליך רשות בהם אלא מה שתרצי עשי בהם לא קנה הבעל ומה שתרצה תעשה בהם
2. Alternatively if her husband does not feed his wife (or give her a maah kesef allocation  of money per week) her productions of her labour entirely belong to herself.(see source below)
3. If she refuses to take food from her husband or accept money (as questioner mentioned) likewise everything that she makes from this point on belongs to herself.(see source below)
   [Chelkas Mechokeik, Even Haezer 81:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Chelkat_Mechokek.81.1?lang=bi)
   ג) הרי כל מעשה ידיה קודש:    היינו בנותן לה מזונות ומעה כסף דאז כל מעשה ידיה הם שלו ויכול להקדישן אבל באינו נותן לה או בהיא אומרת איני ניזוני' ואיני נוטל' מעה כסף אינו יכול להקדיש דבר שאינו שלו:
4. If she eats less than what she is allocated to eat she can keep the left overs(this is why Rivka gave Yaakov 2 goats as it was part of her allocation from Yitzchok that she didn't eat) Tosfos Nazir 24b:
   קימצה מעיסתה שלא הוזלו המזונות אלא קימצה ופיחתה מפיה שלא אכלה כדי שובע דההואמותר הוי ודאי דידה:
5. If the husband injures his wife she keeps the monetory damages and the husband has no *Peiros* from that money.
   [Shulchan Aruch, Even Haezer 83:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.83.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
   הבעל שחבל באשתו וחייב לשלם לה מיד כל הנזק וכל הבשת והצער הכל שלה ואין לבעל בהם פירות
6. The unexpected dividends of those fruit (*peira depeiros*)she gave her husband belong to her and the husband cannot take *peiros* eg. *kefel arba vechamisha* (penalty payments added on for stealing Shemos 21,37 22,3) and the sale of her kesuba during her marriage mentioned in Bava Kamma 89a explained by Tosfos:
   פירא דפירא לא תקינו ליה רבנן. היינו במילי דאתו מעלמא כגון טובת הנאה דכתובה וכגון גונב ולד בהמת מלוג דמשלם כפל לאשה

Comment: +1 but Your second point how do you know the husband does not just feed her and own the fruits/dividens of what is left, (i understnad she owns it but how can she use it before death or divorce?)

Comment: @hazoriz the source of helkat mehokek is ketubot 58b:אמר רב הונא אמר רב יכולה אשה לומר לבעלה איני ניזונת ואיני עושה rashi explains 
    ואיני עושה - לך כלום אלא לעצמי I e it belongs entirely to her.the Halachot follows Rav Huna. Even Reish Lakish (who says she has to work for her husband when he provides her with food) agrees that when the husband does not provide her with food, her earnings belong entirely to herself see Gemara.

Comment: @yosefkorn (i think i already knew everything you wrote) my question was how do you know that it does not become nichsai melug https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.85.7

Comment: @hazoriz if you read the Gemorah I quoted it says clearly that the husband only gets peiros tachas mezonoseho which means he has no rights to the fruit in any situation where she is not fed by him. So since nichse milug means that he gets kinyan peiros while she retains the kinyan haguf, here there is no kinyan peiros ,so since the fruit belong to her they do not get sold for nichse milug, and she can even sell her field without his consent when she doesn't have food.by the way upvoted your question very relevant for Halacha nowadays.

Comment: @yosefkorn (thank you for the +1) she can sell even **his** feild https://www.sefaria.org/Chelkat_Mechokek.70.13 , peiros are not tachas mezonoseha (tachas mezonoseha is the work of her hands) peiros are tachas pidyon see https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.69.5 and https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.78.1

Comment: @yosefkorn also see link in last comment on the OP

Comment: @hazoriz sorry I made a mistake you are 100% right I meant that maase yodeho tachas mezonoseho, and even though peiros tachas pirkonoh she can use the peiros, her land and also his land to provide her food like you quoted. so you answered your own question does the peiros become nichse milog no.

Comment: @yosefkorn a agree that the money need for her support she can use ,but if she makes more money then that , why do you say this surplus does not become nichsai mlog

Comment: @hazoriz I agree with you about the peiros that leftovers go to her husband tachas pirkonoh but maase yodeho go entirely to her even the surplus when he does not give her food that is evident in Kesubos 58a

Comment: @yosefkorn she owns it , but maybe only as nichsai melog, (peros are all his not nichsai melog)

Comment: @hazoriz if you look at the Gemora I quoted you would realise that maa kesef tachas mosar maase yodeho so the husband has no reshus whatsoever for her productions if he didn't give her food or money. This is clear from the Mishna that Rabbi Meir holds that the mosar maase yodeho can only become Hekdesh after she died. If she had to buy land with mosar maase yodeho and the fruit belonged to him then even during her lifetime there would be fruit that would become Hekdesh in the future as Rabbi Meir holds one can be makdish Davar Shelo bo laolom. I think you can finally tick an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Even Haezer 69:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.69.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) is really the operative rule for any practical case today if she out-earns her husband, or simply prefers to manage her own finances. She declares that their incomes are independent, and that's it.

Comment: +1 but how do you know that the husband does not have rights for the fruits of left over money (after used for food and clothing) (we see in EH 83.1 that she owns part of the damages but the husband has the rights for the fruits, )

Comment: Not that her incomes are independent, but her living is totally independent, hence, she must pay her husband the rent etc. This course is very problematic as they will need to manage shared property, and split the expenses.