# Source that you can't tell your wife not to lend to others

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, marriage, nedarim-shevuot, borrowing

Although I heard in a shiur that there is a gemara which says a husband is not allowed to tell his wife not to lend to others since she would eventually develop a bad name, I can't find it - are there any sources in Chazal that say this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Kesubos 72a

> תניא נמי הכי המדיר את אשתו שלא תשאל ושלא תשאיל נפה וכברה ריחים ותנור יוציא ויתן כתובה מפני שמשיאה שם רע בשכינותיה
>   Someone who imposes a vow on his wife that she may not borrow or lend her kitchen utensils like sieve, mill, oven etc.  must divorce his wife and pay her Kesuba because he makes a bad name for his wife among her neighbours

Comment: Is it restricted to kitchen utensils or does it also applies to consumables like flour, salt, sugar?

Comment: @Mindwin the Rambam Isus 13,10 says הדירה שלא תשאל ולא תשאיל מכלי הבית שדרך כל השכנות לשאול אותן ולהשאילן כגון נפה וכברה רחים ותנור וכיוצא בהם- If he imposes a vow upon her not to lend utensils that are usually lent. If she lends her salt and sugar from her allocation i would assume since thats what people normally do it is forbidden fo the husband to stop her (see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84567/when-can-a-wife-use-the-money-she-owns-or-earns-without-her-husbands-permission)