# What or how much did a woman own within the household during Ancient Israel?

Tags: women, shemot-exodus, estates-inheritance, ownership

In [Shemoth/Exodus 21:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.21.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) it states:

> If he marries another wife, her [the first wife's] food, her clothing, and her conjugal rights, shall he not diminish.
>
> אִם-אַחֶרֶת, יִקַּח-לוֹ--שְׁאֵרָהּ כְּסוּתָהּ וְעֹנָתָהּ, לֹא יִגְרָע

If the property is inherited through the males (unless there are no male heirs qualified or eligible then it passes to the daughters), did a wife (or wives) own anything within the household?  Did all household income/property/resources belong to the husband?

As always articles, commentaries, references, and personal insight are always welcomed.

Comment: A woman can keep her earnings if she tells her husband not to support her. In addition, she has rights to two kinds of assets she brings into the marriage, "*Nichsei Melog*" and "*Nichsei Tzon Barzel*" (see [here](https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/2522)). For the rest see the next comment

Comment: related: [When can a wife use the money she owns or earns without her husband's permission?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84567/when-can-a-wife-use-the-money-she-owns-or-earns-without-her-husbands-permission)