# Wife's money belonging to husband

Tags: money

If the wife's money belongs to the husband, does it mean she has no voice in financial decisions?

May he forbid her from having the access to the money (savings accounts) because "it is all his by halacha"?

Where is the line between halacha and financial abuse?

In exchange of what is the husband entitled to his wife's earnings?

Is there a norm of what he has to financially provide for her?

Who is financially obligated to support children, the mother or the father?

Is there an obligation on a woman to feed her children if the husband refuses to pay for them (including tuition)?

Comment: welcome! These are all reasonable questions to be curious about and ask of. However, asking multiple questions all together in one shot is generally discouraged here and unlikely to get you high quality answers. I would suggest resubmitting individual questions one at time to get the best responses. Also, please do not forget to use the search bar to see if any of your questions have already been answered. All the best, enjoy the forum :)

Comment: See: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93658/27180